# How to use QToolButton

Tags: c++, qt

I am trying to create a drop down button using QToolBar.
I tried to do that using the following strategy:

http://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/5377

The problem is that the button doesn't respond immediately when I click on it. It takes several clicks to make the menu appear.

*I guess* I am putting the code in the wrong place, but where else should I put it?

Here is my code:

```
Proto::Proto(QWidget *parent) :
QMainWindow(parent),
ui(new Ui::Proto)
{
 ui->setupUi(this);
 QMenu *menu = new QMenu("Menu");
 QWidgetAction *action = new QWidgetAction(this);
 QPushButton *button2 = new QPushButton("Click me", menu);
 action->setDefaultWidget(button2);
 menu->addAction(action);
 ui->btnVolume->setMenu(menu);
}
```

Please, anyone can help me?
Thanks in advance,

Comment: This code only creates the button, it doesn't handle the click right ?

Comment: Actually it does, since some time it will open the menu. The problem is that when the user clicks on the button, it doesn't respond. It takes several clicks in order to open the menu...

Comment: Just solved it... It was quite simple: just added the line:

        ui->btnVolume->setPopupMode(QToolButton::InstantPopup);

Thanks for your support...!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like you forget to connect your button to a slot (or at least, it's not shown in the piece of code you posted). I just added the `connect()` statement like that

```
QPushButton *button2 = new QPushButton("Click me", menu);

connect(button2, SIGNAL(clicked()), SLOT(dosmth()));

action->setDefaultWidget(button2);
```

and then implemented this simple `dosmth()` Q_SLOT

```
void MainWindow::dosmth() {
    qDebug() << "Hi";
}
```

and at each button click, i get this on the console:

```
Hi
Hi
Hi
```